# Install HHVM on IBM Bluemix

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, hhvm, precompile, pre-compilation

I have a web application on IBM Bluemix. I would like to speed up the app by precompiling the PHP by using Facebook's HHVM. How can this be done? Is this possible on Bluemix?

Thank you,

--

Comment: This is note a close.  While is not directly related to code the question is asking a technical question on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah this actually would be.  It would be a little work to do this but with a build pack you can basically run any executable file.  You would just need to bind to the port that is assigned by environment variable `$PORT`.  Check out [the Cloud Foundry Docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html) on implementing one.  I would take a peak at the C buildpack as well.

The [binary buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-buildpack) will probably be your best starting place.

You can compile your code using HHVM, I pulled out the relevant pieces from [here](https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/building-from-source#ubuntu-14.04-trusty) below.  This needs to be done on **Ubuntu 14.04** as that is what Bluemix runs on.

Install deps:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake binutils-dev build-essential cmake g++ gawk git \
  libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-regex-dev \
  libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-context-dev libbz2-dev libc-client-dev libldap2-dev \
  libc-client2007e-dev libcap-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libdwarf-dev libelf-dev \
  libexpat-dev libgd2-xpm-dev libgoogle-glog-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev libicu-dev \
  libjemalloc-dev libmcrypt-dev libmemcached-dev libmysqlclient-dev libncurses-dev \
  libonig-dev libpcre3-dev libreadline-dev libtbb-dev libtool libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev \
  libevent-dev libmagickwand-dev libinotifytools0-dev libiconv-hook-dev libedit-dev \
  libiberty-dev libxslt1-dev ocaml-native-compilers libsqlite3-dev libyaml-dev libgmp3-dev \
  gperf libkrb5-dev libnotify-dev
```

Downloading the HHVM source-code:

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/hhvm.git --depth=1
cd hhvm
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Build HHVM:

```
cmake -DMYSQL_UNIX_SOCK_ADDR=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock .
make -j [number_of_processor_cores] # eg. make -j 4
sudo make install
```

The installed hhvm binary can be found in `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

That's easy to do with the built-in PHP buildpack. Simply specify a dependency on HHVM in your composer.json file, like below:

`{
    "require": {
        "hhvm": ">=3.5"
    }
}`